# Why is my python card game returning None for every card when restarting?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Streets and Alleys card game and I'm currently having trouble making a new game when the user inputs "r" or if they win a game. Every time, it returns None for every card. I'm not quite sure if it has something to do with my function initialize() or if it's something I have to rewrite in my main(). Here's my code:

```
import cards, random, re
random.seed(100) #random number generator will always generate 
                 #the same 'random' number (needed to replicate tests)

MENU = '''     
Input options:
    MTT s d: Move card from Tableau pile s to Tableau pile d.
    MTF s d: Move card from Tableau pile s to Foundation d.
    MFT s d: Move card from Foundation s to Tableau pile d.
    U: Undo the last valid move.
    R: Restart the game (after shuffling)
    H: Display this menu of choices
    Q: Quit the game       
'''

the_deck = cards.Deck()  

            
def initialize():
    
    '''Establishes two lists and deals the cards
    to the tableau with even lists having 7 cards
    and odd lists having 6 cards'''
    
    foundation = [[], [], [], []]
    
    tableau = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
    checker = False
    
    while checker == False:
        the_deck.shuffle()
    
        for i in range( 7 ):
            tableau[0].append(the_deck.deal())
            
        for i in range (8, 14):
            tableau[1].append(the_deck.deal())
            
        for i in range( 15, 22 ):
            tableau[2].append(the_deck.deal())
            
        for i in range (23, 29):
            tableau[3].append(the_deck.deal())
            
        for i in range( 30, 37):
            tableau[4].append(the_deck.deal())
            
        for i in range (38, 44):
            tableau[5].append(the_deck.deal())
            
        for i in range( 45, 52 ):
            tableau[6].append(the_deck.deal())
            
        for i in range (53, 59):
            tableau[7].append(the_deck.deal())
            
            checker = True
            
            continue
    
    return tableau, foundation


def display(tableau, foundation):
    '''Each row of the display will have
       tableau - foundation - tableau
       Initially, even indexed tableaus have 7 cards; odds 6.
       The challenge is the get the left vertical bars
       to line up no matter the lengths of the even indexed piles.'''
    
    # To get the left bars to line up we need to
    # find the length of the longest even-indexed tableau list,
    #     i.e. those in the first, leftmost column
    # The "4*" accounts for a card plus 1 space having a width of 4
    max_tab = 4*max([len(lst) for i,lst in enumerate(tableau) if i%2==0])
    # display header
    print("{1:>{0}s} | {2} | {3}".format(max_tab+2,"Tableau","Foundation","Tableau"))
    # display tableau | foundation | tableau
    for i in range(4):
        left_lst = tableau[2*i] # even index
        right_lst = tableau[2*i + 1] # odd index
        # first build a string so we can format the even-index pile
        s = ''
        s += "{}: ".format(2*i)  # index
        for c in left_lst:  # cards in even-indexed pile
            s += "{} ".format(c)
        # display the even-indexed cards; the "+3" is for the index, colon and space
        # the "{1:<{0}s}" format allows us to incorporate the max_tab as the width
        # so the first vertical-bar lines up
        print("{1:<{0}s}".format(max_tab+3,s),end='')
        # next print the foundation
        # get foundation value or space if empty
        found = str(foundation[i][-1]) if foundation[i] else ' '
        print("|{:^12s}|".format(found),end="")
        # print the odd-indexed pile
        print("{:d}: ".format(2*i+1),end="") 
        for c in right_lst:
            print("{} ".format(c),end="") 
        print()  # end of line
    print()
    print("-"*80)
     
     
def valid_tableau_to_tableau(tableau,s,d):
    '''Checks to see if you can move a card
    from one tableau to another'''
    
    if len(tableau[s]) == 0:
        return False
    
    card_source = tableau[s][len(tableau[s])-1]
    
    if d > 7: #makes sure destination isn't greater than 7
        return False
    
    if card_source.rank() >= 1 and len(tableau[d]) == 0:
        return True
    
    try:
        card_destination = tableau[d][len(tableau[d])-1]
    except:
        return False
    
    if card_source.rank() == card_destination.rank()-1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
def move_tableau_to_tableau(tableau,s,d):
    '''Moves the selected card from a tableau to another'''
    
    if valid_tableau_to_tableau(tableau, s, d):
        tableau[d].append(tableau[s].pop()) #move the card
        return True
    else: #figure out when to return True or False
        print("Error in move: {} , {} , {}".format("MTT", s, d))
        return False


def valid_foundation_to_tableau(tableau,foundation,s,d):
    '''Checks to see if you can move a card
    from the foundation to a tableau'''
    
    if len(foundation[s]) == 0:
        return False
    
    card_source = foundation[s][len(foundation[s])-1]
    
    if len(tableau[d]) == 0: #checks that foundation can move to empty tableau
        return True
    
    try: #checks that tableau destination has a card
        card_destination = tableau[d][len(tableau[d])-1]
    except:
        return False
    
    if card_source.rank() == card_destination.rank()-1: #source code is one lower than the destination card
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
    

def move_foundation_to_tableau(tableau,foundation,s,d):
    '''Moves the selected card from the foundation to a tableau'''
    
    if valid_foundation_to_tableau(tableau, foundation, s, d):
        tableau[d].append(foundation[s].pop())
        return True
    else:
        print("Error in move: {} , {} , {}".format("MFT", s, d))
        return False

def valid_tableau_to_foundation(tableau,foundation,s,d):
    '''Checks to see if you can move a card
    from one tableau to the foundation'''
    
    if len(foundation[d]) == 0:
        card_source = tableau[s][len(tableau[s])-1]
        
        if card_source.rank() == 1: 
            return True  #True if source card is an Ace
        else: 
            return False
        
    else:
        try: #checks if destination and source has card
            card_source = tableau[s][len(tableau[s])-1]
            card_destination = foundation[d][len(foundation[d])-1]
        except:
            return False
        
        if (card_source.rank()-1 == card_destination.rank() and card_source.suit() == card_destination.suit()):
            return True #checks if suits match as well as ranked accordingly 
        else:
            return False

def move_tableau_to_foundation(tableau, foundation, s,d):
    '''Moves the selected card from a tableau to the foundation'''
    
    if valid_tableau_to_foundation(tableau, foundation, s, d):
        foundation[d].append(tableau[s].pop())
        return True
    else:
        print("Error in move: {} , {} , {}".format("MTF", s, d))
        return False
    
    
def invalid_tableau_to_foundation(tableau, foundation, s, d):
    ''''Undo a move from tableau to foundation'''
    foundation[d].append(tableau[s].pop())
    return True

def invalid_tableau_to_tableau(tableau, s, d):
    ''''Undo a move from tableau to another tableau'''
    tableau[d].append(tableau[s].pop())
    return True

def invalid_foundation_to_tableau(tableau, foundation, s, d):
    ''''Undo a move from the foundation to a tableau'''
    tableau[d].append(foundation[s].pop())
    return True

def check_for_win(foundation):
    '''Checks to see if all lists of the foundation
    are filled with 13 cards each (Full suit).'''
    
    #checks if all foundation lists have all 13 cards in them
    if (len(foundation[0]) == 13) and (len(foundation[1]) == 13) and (len(foundation[2]) == 13) and (len(foundation[3]) == 13):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def get_option():
    '''Prints option menu and takes
    user input to determine which 
    option will follow'''
    
    user_input = input("\nInput an option (MTT,MTF,MFT,U,R,H,Q): ").upper()
    
    if not (re.search('M[A-Z][A-Z] [0-9] [0-9]', user_input) \
            or user_input == "U" or user_input == "R" or user_input == "H" or user_input == "Q"):
        print("Error in option:", user_input)
        return None
    
    else:
        if (user_input == "U" or user_input == "R" or user_input == "H" or user_input == "Q"):
            return [user_input]
        else:
            option_list = user_input.split()
            mode = option_list[0]
            source = int(option_list[1])
            destination = int(option_list[2])
            
            if mode[1] == "T":
                if source not in range(0, 8):
                    print("Error in Source.")
                    return None
                
            if mode[1] == "F":
                if source not in range(0, 4):
                    print("Error in Source.")
                    return None
                
            if mode[2] == "T":
                if destination not in range(0, 8):
                    print("Error in Destination")
                    return None
                
            if mode[2] == "F":
                if destination not in range(0, 4):
                    print("Error in Destination")
                    return None
                
            return [mode, source, destination]

        
def main():  
    c = ""
    option_list = None
    win = False
    continuing = False
    turn = True
    redo = []
    
    
    
    print("\nWelcome to Streets and Alleys Solitaire.\n")
    
    tableau, foundation = initialize()
    
    while c != "Q":
        
        if turn:
            display(tableau, foundation)
            print(MENU) 
            turn = False
        option_list = get_option()
        while option_list == None:
            option_list = get_option()
        moving_string = option_list[0]
        if len(option_list) == 1:
            c = option_list[0]
            
        else:
            c = moving_string
            if moving_string == "MTT":
                continuing = move_tableau_to_tableau(tableau, option_list[1], option_list[2])
                if continuing:
                    list_of_moves = ["MTT", option_list[1], option_list[2]]
                    redo.append(list_of_moves)
                    
            elif moving_string == "MTF":
                continuing = move_tableau_to_foundation(tableau, foundation, option_list[1], option_list[2])
                
                if continuing:
                    list_of_moves = ["MTF", option_list[1], option_list[2]]
                    redo.append(list_of_moves)
                    
            else:
                continuing = move_foundation_to_tableau(tableau, foundation, option_list[1], option_list[2])
                
                if continuing:
                    list_of_moves = ["MFT", option_list[1], option_list[2]]
                    redo.append(list_of_moves)
                    
            if continuing:
                win = check_for_win(foundation)
                if not win:
                    display(tableau, foundation)
                
            if win:
                print("You won!\n")
                display(tableau, foundation)
                print("\n- - - - New Game. - - - -\n")
                tableau, foundation = initialize()
                display(tableau, foundation)
                turn = True
                
        if c == "R":
            tableau, foundation = initialize()
            display(tableau, foundation)
            
        if c == "H":
            print(MENU)
                
        if c == "U":
            if len(redo) == 0:
                print("No moves to undo.")
            else:
                newer_move = redo.pop()
                if newer_move[0] == "MTT":
                    invalid_tableau_to_tableau(tableau, newer_move[2], newer_move[1])
                    
                if newer_move[0] == "MTF":
                    invalid_tableau_to_foundation(tableau, foundation, newer_move[2], newer_move[1])
                    
                if newer_move[0] == "MFT":
                    invalid_foundation_to_tableau(tableau, foundation, newer_move[2], newer_move[1])
                    
                x = newer_move[0]
                y = str(newer_move[1])
                z = str(newer_move[2])
                    
                print("Undo:", x, y, z)
                display(tableau, foundation)
                
    print("Thank you for playing.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: You **must** provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show us `cards`, but I'm betting that returns a generator, and after you've gone through it once, there's nothing left.  You should generate a new deck every time.  I don't know what you were trying to do with `checker`, but clearly that was silly.  I'm also not sure why you were dealing 8 columns; the 8th column is never going to have any cards.

```
def initialize():
    
    '''Establishes two lists and deals the cards
    to the tableau with even lists having 7 cards
    and odd lists having 6 cards'''
    
    foundation = [[], [], [], []]    
    tableau = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

    the_deck = cards.Deck()  
    the_deck.shuffle()
    
    for i in range(7):
        for j in range(7 - i%2):
            tableau[i].append(the_deck.deal())
    
    return tableau, foundation
```

Comment: Ok that fixed that issue, but now im having an issue where if the user wants to undo a move two times in a row, after the second undo, my program breaks

Comment: To make that work, you need to keep a stack of all of the moves that have been made.  That stack needs to have enough information to tell you how to do the 'undo'.  Every new move pushes into the undo-stack, and each undo command pops an entry and restores the old state.

Comment: I do establish a list of moves made in main, it's just when the second undo is made, it prompts with an "IndexError: list index out of range" and it's in my function invalid_tableau_to_foundation. It doesn't like the line "foundation[d].append(tableau[s].pop())"

Comment: You have your undos backwards.  If you undo a "tableau to foundation" move, then you need to move FROM foundation back TO tableau.